# How to distort a color attribute

Tags: texturing, materials, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes, vector-mapping

I’m looking to give a natural look to dirt paths by setting up bounding boxes that distorts the color with noise to simulate realistic erosion.

In the first 2 images I have successfully set the bounding box system but now I’m looking to add noise similar to how in the 3rd image when I used an image texture

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you could try distorting the sample position.